# "I'm cooperating!"

Tags: word-usage

One day, I was chatting with my friend in English.
We were talking about something and we both knew that we were joking.
The conversation is as follows:

My Friend: I am going to watch all episodes of the Community!

Me: Wuuuuuuuut? There are five seasons in total, are you sure about this?

My Friend: Right I was just joking (Blackmoon face)

Me: I Know. I'm cooperating. Ha...

By the word cooperating, I wanted to tell her I knew that she was joking all the time, but I acted like I did not know she was joking and replied to her. I wonder if you guys could understand how I use the word "cooperating" and if I used it right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in colloquial English people would normally say something like **"I was just playing along"** or **"I just went along with it"**.

> **play along:** cooperate or pretend to cooperate

(Princeton WordNet)

Here's another idiom:

> **go along with the gag**
>
> **To cooperate in continuing a joke**, hoax, or similar phenomenon initiated by others.
>
> Synonyms
>
> (to cooperate in continuing a joke): **play along**

(https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_along_with_the_gag)

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with _cooperating_.

Comment: Really @ColinFine ?  I've never heard anyone say they are co-operating with a joke.  It's easy to understand the intended meaning, but it is not idiomatic.  I'd say co-operating is wrong.  Using it, in this way - informally, with a friend -  reveals that you are not a native speaker.  Surely?

Comment: @Dan: I agree that it's not idiomatic. That doesn't make it wrong.